# Verificar conexão fechada

Tags: php

Como posso verificar se uma conexão foi fechada de fato?

```
    $con = new Conexao();
    $con->abrirConexao();
    ...
    $con->fecharConexao();
```

Eu utilizo uma variável para instanciar a classe `Conexao` que está em outro arquivo. Gostaria apenas de saber como posso verificar se o método `fecharConexão()` de fato fechou a conexão anteriormente aberta.

Meu método para fechar a conexão é esse:

```
public function fecharConexao(){
    return mysqli_close($this->conexao);          
}
```

Só gostaria de uma notificação (só para eu saber) de que a conexão encerrou. Como faço isso?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A função `mysqli_close()` retorna valor booleano

`true`: indica que executou com sucesso

`false`: indica que houve algum erro.

Basicamente, apenas verifique o valor de retorno.

Se retornar `true`, a conexão foi fechada.

Comment: só completando, se você quer poder recuperar isso a hora que quiser, guarde o retorno em um atributo da classe. Exemplo: A conexão iniciou `$this->aberta = true` a conexão terminou `$this->aberta = false` isso possibilitará criar um método como `public function estaAberta()` e essa função retorna o valor de `$this->aberta`.